# Should I use pwd or tilde plus (~+)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Both `pwd` and `~+` offer the same info, the current directory path.

So my question is, is there one I should use over the other? Is `~+` supported in all systems as I suppose `pwd` is? If so, `~+` would be more of an eye candy to use.

One example of use would be:

```
var=$($(pwd)/folder/another/script -v)
var=$(~+/folder/another/script -v)
```

Comment: Do you need the full path of the working directory expanded? Wouldn't just  `./folder/another/script` do?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, theres no need to in that specific case but there could be in another. And in that case i would like to know which one would be best.

Comment: What do you mean by "all systems"?  There's a "bash" tag on this question.  Not all systems have bash, so that's already not "all systems."

Comment: Since the tilde expansion is a feature of the _shell_, are you using the same shell (`bash`?) on all the systems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~+` doesn't appear to be standard, [only `~username` and the tilde alone are defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01). And e.g. Dash and Busybox don't support `~+`. The command `pwd`, as well as the shell variable `$PWD` are standard, though, so either `"$(pwd)"` or `"$PWD"` should work.

In most cases, you'd refer to the current directory with just `.`, but if you need the full path expanded, I would normally go with `"$PWD"`. As opposed to the variable, the command substitution requires spawning a new process in many shells, a needless overhead.

Note that you need to quote the expansion, in case the path to the current directory contains e.g. white space. <sub>(Or whatever your `$IFS` contains, plus glob characters.)</sub>

Though if you want to resolve any symlinks in the current working directory, you'll need to use `"$(pwd -P)"`. Both `$PWD` and `$(pwd)` would show the path you used to go there, with the symlink (in the shells I tried anyway, didn't check if that's a given). E.g.:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ ln -s /tmp/foo /tmp/link
$ cd /tmp/link
$ echo "$PWD"; pwd; pwd -P
/tmp/link
/tmp/link
/tmp/foo
```